# how to get the RadTab of RadPageView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am having following telerik tabstrip control : -

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="rtsMyTabs" runat="server" MultiPageID="rmpMyMultiPage"
    SelectedIndex="0" Align="Justify" Width="970px" CssClass="tab-border-custom"
    Skin="Simple">
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Step1" Width="280px" Selected="True">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab Text="Step2" Width="280px">
        </telerik:RadTab>
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="rmpProjectStatus" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="pageView"
    Width="100%">
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px" />
    </telerik:RadPageView>
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox2" runat="server" Width="170px" />
    </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

I would like to know Tab Index of "txtMyTextBox2" in code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy this request is :

```
var a = rmpProjectStatus.FindPageViewByID(txtMyTextBox2.Parent.ID).Index ;
```

It will get you the index of that Page that contains the desired control.

Comment: txtMyTextBox2.Parent.ID returned - "ctl00" and rmpProjectStatus.FindPageViewByID(txtMyTextBox2.Parent.ID).Index returned - "rmpProjectStatus.FindPageViewByID(txtMyTextBox2.Parent.ID).Index is Null"

Comment: @anilpurswani You may need to set the ClientIDMode="Static" property on those controls so the .Net framework does not auto generate an id for you for the controls.